# Apple Push Notification From Rails App

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Houston Gem for sending push notifications from my Rails app.I tried printing the response from the API.It just returns an Integer(120,124,192,etc...)

Is there any way from my Rails app that I could understand if the Push notification was processed successfully.

```
certificate_enterprise = File.read("config/enterprise.pem")
connection = Houston::Connection.new("apn://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195", certificate, pass_phrase)
connection.open
connection.write(notification.message)
connection.close
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The APNS service doesn't provide feedback on whether it has received and processed a notification, but you can connect to a feedback service to see if it has failed to deliver to any of the devices you've attempted to communicate with: [APNS feedback service documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html).

Comment: Is there any method so that I could get access to the feedbak service from the gem that I am using?

Comment: According to the GitHub page, there is a method for it: https://github.com/nomad/Houston (scroll down to 'Feedback').